# Use child-item result object in array

Tags: arrays, powershell, backup

I encountered a problem in PowerShell  in listing its child items.

```
$file = Get-ChildItem \\compname\c$\folder\ -Recurse -Filter *filename.txt* |
        Select-Object -Property DirectoryName, FullName
```

When I try this to get its objects it was empty:

```
$file.FullName
```

or

```
$file.DirectoryName
```

If there is a many files in that directory with the same file name, how can I backup up those files in the same folder by by adding .bak on its file extension.

Answer (score 1):

You're still using PowerShell v2 or earlier. These early versions don't support [member enumeration](https://blogs.msdn.microsoft.com/powershell/2012/06/13/new-v3-language-features/) on arrays, which would allow you to access properties of array elements via the array object itself. Instead you get an empty result, because the array object does not have a property `DirectoryName` or `FullName`.

If you can't upgrade to at least PowerShell v3 you can work around this issue with a loop:

```
$file | ForEach-Object { $_.FullName }
```

or by expanding the property:

```
$file | Select-Object -Expand FullName
```